# Complex Borel Measure Decomposes as Discrete + Continuous Measures?

Tags: measure-theory

I am trying to prove that any complex Borel measure $\mu$ on a measure space $(X, \mathfrak{M})$ decomposes into the sum of a discrete measure $\lambda$ and a continuous measure $\nu$, $\mu = \lambda + \nu$.  It is given as a theorem without proof in a book I came across, but haven't been able to locate the proof.

I am skeptical that no conditions need to be placed on $X$ as well; I would just assume that $X$ is $T_1$ minimally.  So I am wondering what conditions might be necessary for this to be true.

Comment: I believe Benedetto has a proof of this in his book Spectral Synthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{A_n : n \geq 1\}$ be a maximal collection of pairwise disjoint subsets of $X$ of positive measure such that for every subset $B \subseteq A_n$, either $\mu(B) = \mu(A_n)$ or $\mu(B) = 0$ (so $A_n$ are atoms). Let $Y = X \backslash \bigcup_{n \geq 1} A_n$. Let $\lambda(A) = \sum_{n \geq 1} (A \cap A_n)$, $\nu(A) = \mu(A \cap Y)$.